# Problems with stretching center div between fixed width divs

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, width

I have 3 divs inline. 2 of which have set px widths(outside divs). I want the center div to fill in all the space between the two outside divs when the window adjusts.

Here's an example of my attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ZPHT

```
    #div_1 {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: left;}
#div_2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#div_3 {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    width: 350px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Here's an idea of what I want it to look like:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q8eVz

Any help is very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So what's wrong with your example?

Comment: You mean like http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/3ZPHT/2/ ?

Comment: Yeah just like that. I overlooked the html and just looked at the css. I didn't realize the middle div should be listed after the outside divs in the html. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3ZPHT/1/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="div_1">LEFT COL STATIC WIDTH 300px</div>
    <div id="div_3">RIGHT COL STATIC WIDTH 350px</div>
    <div id="div_2">CENTER COL DYNAMIC WIDTH</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div_1 {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: left;}
#div_2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#div_3 {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    width: 350px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've just been battling with the CSS forever. I didn't even think of altering the html and putting the middle div after the outside divs.